# How to configure autofac to inject a type for an interface when initializing a Web API controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have a WebAPI Controller which has a dependency on another class:

```
 public class HealthCheckController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
    {
        private readonly IHealthCheckReport _healthCheckReport;

        public HealthCheckController(IHealthCheckReport healthCheckReport)
        {
            this._healthCheckReport = healthCheckReport;
        }
}
```

I'm using Autofac and inside the Register method of my WebApiConfig class, I've added:

```
 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
 builder.RegisterType<HealthCheckReport>().As<IHealthCheckReport>();
 var container = builder.Build();

 // Set the dependency resolver for Web API.
 var webApiResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = webApiResolver;
```

But when I call the Index() action, it complains that my controller doesn't have a default constructor. Whereas, I expected Autofac just magically inject the type I have registered above.

How should this be configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the api controller too.

```
  builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Source: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WebApiIntegration

Comment: Unfortunately, while the consistency between the MVC and Web API interfaces results in familiarity, it also creates confusion.